# При чтении файла пишет отказано в доступе

Tags: java, android

В приложении не читает файл и пишет что отказано в доступе. В манифесте написал разрешения и  всеравно.

```
void readfile (String name)  {
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);

         File file = new File(dir,"/"+ name);

         try {
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
             String line;

             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 array[size] = line;
                 size++;
             }
             text_film.setText(array[2]);
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
             text_film.setText(dir + "/"+name);
             Log.e(TAG, "readfile: ",e);
         }


     }
```

Вот такая ошибка:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/Documents/textt.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Путь получается такой /storage/sdcard0/Documents/textt.txt это файл есть. 
В манифесте код

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.premission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.premission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: добавил. Еще пробовал заново запрашивать рарешения по без результатно

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.premission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.premission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


про application я знаю

Comment: Какая версия android API на используемом девайсе?

Comment: Версия API 19 KitKat

Comment: Откуда такая уверенность что путь к файлу именно такой?

Comment: getpath такой показывает путь

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider
взял отсюда метод и работает